# Looping through JSON data and printing out a field using Perl (Not a HASH ref)

Tags: json, perl, hash, foreach

I need to loop through several jsons and print out index 1 of each...

I start with a generated string containing my JSON data. I then decode the string and dump it to show exactly what I'm working with:

```
my $decoded = decode_json $string
print Dumper $string
```

This results in the following output:

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'hdr' => [
                   1,
                   'acknowledged',
                   '',
                   '/home/clanier/dev/test/sds-test/data/JPLIDR2015169.64575',
                   '2015/271-19:10:39.0101355',
                   '2015/271-19:10:39.2599252',
                   ''
                 ]
      },
      {
        'hdr' => [
                   2,
                   'acknowledged',
                   '',
                   '/home/clanier/dev/test/sds-test/data/JPLIDR2015169.64575',
                   '2015/271-19:10:39.3928414',
                   '2015/271-19:10:39.6397269',
                   ''
                 ]
      },
      {
        'hdr' => [
                   3,
                   'acknowledged',
                   '',
                   '/home/clanier/dev/test/sds-test/data/JPLIDR2015169.64575',
                   '2015/271-19:10:39.7726375',
                   '2015/271-19:10:40.0162758',
                   ''
                 ]
      }
    ];
```

Now I try to loop through this and print the word acknowledged for each one:

```
foreach my $hdr ( $decoded->{hdr} ) {
  print $hdr->[1];
}
```

I looked to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258387/accessing-values-of-json-structure-in-perl) for help, but it appears I cannot even get as far as the original poster, due to "Not a HASH reference" errors. I was able to print a specific one previously, but I need to loop through and print all of them. This was the code for that: `print $$decoded[0]->{'hdr'}->[1];`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$decoded` is an array reference, not a hash reference. You can't dereference it as a hash: `->{`.

You can dereference it as an array, though:

```
for my $hdr (@$decoded) {
    print $hdr->{hdr}[1];
}
```

See [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut)
 for more information about references in Perl.