# Accessing elements in a list of json in perl

Tags: perl

I have the following object

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'value' => {
                         'a' => 'd',
                         'b' => 'e',
                         'c' => 'f'
                       }
          },
          {
            'value' => {
                         'a' => 'g',
                         'b' => 'h',
                         'c' => 'x'
                       }
          }
        ];
```

I have to traverse this object to get values for a,b,c. 
Please can someone help ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, $VAR1[0] , $VAR1->{0}

Comment: This article is likely to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258387/accessing-values-of-json-structure-in-perl.  I would mark it as a duplicate but already votes to close for other reasons.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you don't actually have a variable called `$VAR1` - that's just the output from `Data::Dumper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach my $arr (@$VAR1) {
    print $arr->{value}->@{ ('a'..'c') };
}
```

Or even shorter :

```
print map{ $_->{value}->@{ ('a'..'c') } } @{ $VAR1 }[0..$#$VAR1];
```

#### OUTPUT

```
defghx
```

Comment: or `0..$#$VAR1`